# Microsoft Power Automate - Excel to Outlook

Tags: excel, outlook, office365, power-automate, microsoft365

I'd like tu extract some dates from my excel table, verify that dates are not expired. Then send an email to comunicate what dates are expired.

the actions i made are:
Recurrence
list rows from table
apply for each where in boxes:
box1: dateColumn (the column's name where are written dates)
box2: grater then
box3:UctNow()

unfortunately it extracts from excel an other format of dates, for example
if cell B2 is: 10/25/2023 it extracts from excel --> 45224

how i can solve it?
i tried some formatting function like: dateformat(item(), mm/dd/yyyy) and insert into the first box of conditions and thousand other tries. But it do not works

thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

In List rows present in a table action => choose advanced options => DateTime Format => ISO Format

just like this screenshot
https://images.app.goo.gl/b736PzjCLJRKiJgk7